# How to get values from treeview checkbox - on which event do I have to write code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I have code to get values from treeview checkbox. But I am not getting on which event I should write it so that it will work properly. I tried it on `treeview1.SelectedNodeChanged`, but it is not working. My code is:

```
protected void TV_Account_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TreeNode tn in this.TV_Account.Nodes)
    {
        if (tn.Checked == true)
        {
            ListBox1.Items.Add(tn.Value);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: plz help me out.. if u need more clarification about problem den, plz let me know.. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the AfterCheck and BeforeCheck events.

Comment: plz help me out.. if u need more clarification about problem den, plz let me know.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: der are no such events availabe with treeview.